# Application Security on Cloud static analysis not working for me

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, bluemix-app-scan

I need some help with using the Application Security on Cloud application.  I am trying to use the free plan to do a static scan.  I have installed the eclipse plugin and when attempting to scan a project I get this error:
A connection to the Static Analyzer scan manager service could not be established. Re-install Static Analyzer plug-ins and try again. If this problem persists, contact your IBM support representative.   During my set up I did select IBM Bluemix as the location for the service.  Set up instructions mentioned giving proxy details if running behind a proxy server.  I'm not aware of any proxies, I'm connected to the IBM network via ATT net client.

I have also tried scanning from within Bluemix console an app of mine that was connected to the Application Security on Cloud service.  The scan appeared to have started but never completed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason you are having difficulty is that you are entering your Bluemix ID and password when prompted by ASoC after selecting to scan your code.

These are not the correct credentials to enter.  The Service Binding ID and password must be used.  See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJJF_1.0.0/ApplicationSecurityonCloud/src_irx_gen_ide.html

If you have done this and still have trouble, it's going to be best to open a support ticket so that we can investigate.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that Eclipse needed to be restarted as administrator after installing the Eclipse plugin.  After installing the plugin restart Eclipse as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, deleting C:\Users\*userName*\.appscan solved the issue for me. After deleting that directory and restarting Eclipse, I was prompted for my ID and Secret on the next attempt and the connection succeeded.